# Nextflow pull Singularity image errors

Tags: java, singularity-container, nextflow

I'm running into errors pulling a Singularity image in a Nextflow pipeline that has worked on other clusters. I believe this error has to do with Java, though I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this and am using updated Java and Nextflow versions. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot errors related to a Singularity pull would be great. Thank you in advance!

```
Pulling Singularity image docker://ksw9/mtb-call [cache /labs/test/Pipeline/tmp/ksw9-mtb-call.img]
Exception in thread "Thread-2" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: exception while reading process stream
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods$TextDumper.run(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:281)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:176)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods$TextDumper.run(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:493)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a network connection issue, rather than an issue with Java or Nextflow exactly. The stream appears to have been closed unexpectedly:

> `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

Usually this happens if your network connection is lost or if the remote service terminates for whatever reason. If your university (or research institute) imposes some resource limitations like a download quota, then exceeding this limit could cause the stream to be closed unexpectedly.

Using Nextflow, it is recommended to provide a centralized cache directory using either the `NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR` environment variable or by defining the `singularity.cacheDir` in your `nextflow.config`<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/container.html#singularity-docker-hub)</sup>. For example:

```
singularity {

  cacheDir = '/path/to/container/images'
}
```

If you're unable to pull the images directly, another way would be to pull them to your local machine and `scp` the images into the above `cacheDir`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've defined the NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR environment variable. My error now is that the singularity pull step truncates with no explanation: Error executing process > 'TrimFastQ (1)'

Caused by:
  Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name ksw9-mtb-call.img.pulling.1677175699580 docker://ksw9/mtb-call > /dev/null
  status : 143
  message:
    INFO:    Converting OCI blobs to SIF format
    INFO:    Starting build...
    Getting image source signatures...INFO:    Creating SIF file...
Job ended at Thu Feb 23 11:29:25 MST 2023

Comment: @ksw What's the output of `singularity pull --name ksw9-mtb-call.img.pulling.1677175699580 docker://ksw9/mtb-call`? If this command succeeds on another machine, rename the image to `ksw9-mtb-call.img` and move (or `scp`) it to your `NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR`. Nextflow should then be able to use the cached image file.